# is using a PUT with side affects acceptable (REST)

Tags: language-agnostic, api, rest

I want to create an undo history whenever the user updates a form. Because it's an update, I want to use a PUT request. However, I read that [PUT needs to have no side effects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7016785/is-put-delete-idempotent-with-rest-automatic).

Is it acceptable to use PUT here? Are there better alternatives?

`PUT  /person/F02E395A235`

```
{
   time: 1234567,
   fields: {
      name: 'John',
      age: '41'
   }
}
```

In the server

```
doPut('person/:personId',
   // create a new person snapshot
)
```

Edit:

The history will be visible to the user, calling multiple times would result in multiple versions.

The solution was to check if the version was unique before creating it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The people drafting HTTP/2 were a lot more verbose about their ideas of what HTTP should do, while retaining the old meaning. Let's see what the HTTP/2 draft spec has to say about idempotence:

> [**4.2.2.  Idempotent Methods**](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-httpbis-p2-semantics-25#section-4.2.2)

> A request method is considered "idempotent" if the intended effect on
> the server of multiple identical requests with that method is the
> same as the effect for a single such request.Of the request methods
> defined by this specification, PUT, DELETE, and safe request methods   are idempotent.

> Like the definition of safe, the idempotent property only applies to
> what has been requested by the user; a server is free to log each
> request separately, **retain a revision control history, or implement
> other non-idempotent side-effects for each idempotent request**.

The *intended effect on the server* for each such a PUT request is to *update the resource identified by that URI*. This is exactly what happens in your case.

That you decide to version resources doesn't really matter here. If you don't want to create a new version when nothing has changed, you'll need to compare the payload in the PUT request with the most recent (or otherwise identified) version of the resource, and when none of the properties have changed you can choose to *not create a new version*.

---

Your edit:

> The history will be visible to the user, calling multiple times would result in multipleversions

As far as the resource is concerned, that is no *side effect*. The resource at that URI does not change (the same properties get PUT). History is just metadata, as it most probably is requested by a different URI or with different request headers.

Comment: Excepted because you answer my specific problem: "is it acceptable for PUT to create a user visible history", And give me a solution, thanks

Comment: To what problem is that a solution? That the `time` property gets updated? I think that is metadata too, even though it is _in_ the resource.

Comment: The problem was that if multiple PUTs were sent, the user would get a long undo history with redundant information. checking for uniqueness solves that

Answer (score 14):

HTTP distinguishes between two properties:

- Idempotency
- Safety

Idempotency is defined by the spec as follows:

> Methods can also have the property of "*idempotence*" in that (aside from error or expiration issues) the side-effects of **N > 0** identical requests is the same as for a single request. The methods `GET`, `HEAD`, `PUT` and `DELETE` share this property. Also, the methods `OPTIONS` and `TRACE` *SHOULD NOT* have side effects, and so are inherently idempotent.

And safety:

> In particular, the convention has been established that the `GET` and `HEAD` methods *SHOULD NOT* have the significance of taking an action other than retrieval. These methods ought to be considered "*safe*". This allows user agents to represent other methods, such as `POST`, `PUT` and `DELETE`, in a special way, so that the user is made aware of the fact that a possibly unsafe action is being requested.
>
> Naturally, it is not possible to ensure that the server does not generate side-effects as a result of performing a `GET` request; in fact, some dynamic resources consider that a feature. The important distinction here is that the user did not request the side-effects, so therefore cannot be held accountable for them.

Note that safety implies idempotency: if a method has no side-effects then performing it multiple times will yield the same side-effect as performing it once, namely none.

This puts the methods into three categories:

- safe (and thus also idempotent): `GET`, `HEAD`, `OPTION`, `TRACE`
- idempotent but not necessarily safe: `PUT`, `DELETE`
- neither idempotent nor safe: `POST`

> PUT needs to have no side affects.

That is wrong. `PUT` is idempotent but not safe. The *whole point* of `PUT` is to have a side-effect, namely updating a resource. What idempotency means is that updating the same resource with the same contents multiple times should have the same effect as updating it only once.

Note the last paragraph in the section about safety [emphasis mine]:

> Naturally, it is not possible to ensure that the server does not generate side-effects as a result of performing a `GET` request; in fact, some dynamic resources consider that a feature. **The important distinction here is that the user did not request the side-effects, so therefore cannot be held accountable for them**.

Although this sentence talks about `GET` and safety, we can assume that the authors also meant to apply the same reasoning to `PUT` and idempotency. IOW: `PUT` should have only one *user-visible* side-effect, namely updating the named resource. It *may* have other side-effects, but the user cannot be held responsible for them.

For example, the fact that `PUT` is idempotent means that I can retry it as often as I want: the spec *guarantees* that executing it multiple times will be exactly the same as executing it once. It's perfectly valid to create a backlog of old revisions as a side-effect of those multiple `PUT` requests. However, if, as a result of multiple retries, your database fills up with a backlog of old revisions, that is not my problem, it's yours.

IOW: you are allowed to have as many side-effects as you want, but

1. it must look to the user as if their requests were idempotent
2. you are responsible for those side-effects, not the user

Comment: Yep, idempotency is about the state of the resource being put, not about any other server/service state that is affected by the act of the PUT.

Comment: Upvote for great explanation, of safety and idempotency in Rest

Comment: Great explanation.  However, you make several statements like this: "The whole point of PUT is to have a side effect, namely updating a resource."  That seems like a contradiction unless you mean something different by the term "side effect" than "something secondary or unintentional that happens in addition to the primary, intended effect."

Comment: @MarredCheese: I am using the term in its standard programming meaning, which basically means "any 'result' that is not the return value".

Comment: Ah, of course.  Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: @MarredCheese: The difference is important, in that e.g. idempotency guarantees that you can repeat operations without causing harm, but you cannot change the order. I.e. deleting a file multiple times has the same effect as deleting it once, but creating and then deleting a file or deleting and then creating a file do not have the same effect. Whereas, a side-effect free operation will never have, well, a side-effect, and so the order doesn't matter. If I read file a and then file b, or I do it the other way around, or I do it at the same time, the result will be the same.

Answer (score 2):

You are correct that **PUT needs to have no side affects**, however I would add something to this.

> PUT needs to have no side affects on the resource for which that PUT operation is being performed

You are updating a `person` resource which is identified as `F02E395A235`, so using PUT is correct. Now as a business rule you also keep track of changes which is invisible to the calling entity (consumer of the REST service). This will not add a new item in the `person` resource. The historical snapshot will not be accessible using the `/person/` endpoint. So I believe, PUT should be perfectly acceptable in this case.

Comment: No side effects on the resource being put, but any number of side effects on other stuff (counters, logging, audit traces, ...) are perfectly acceptable.